# Massive performance problems with Webpack & Eclipse in SpringBoot project

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, webpack

I'm using SpringBoot for the backend, react for the front-end. Developing with Eclipse and packing with webpack. For some reason, when I start the app through Eclipse and run "webpack --watch --mode development" through the console, I get massive performance problems (computer virtually freezes) as soon as I start editing any js files. I'm assuming this is somehow related to watch mode and Eclipse. Please help me ID causes and solutions.

Here's my webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main/js/app.js",
    devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",
    cache: true,
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main/resources/static/built"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main/js"),
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.mvn'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.settings'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'java'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'test'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'target'),
        ],
        aggregateTimeout: 2000,
        poll: 4000,
    }
};
```

and here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "life",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "life app",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router": "^6.10.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
        "rest": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "webpack --watch",
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "webpack --watch --mode development"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "webpack": "^5.76.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
    },
    "cache": true,
    "parallelism": 4
}
```

Side note: watch mode works to update to bundle.js file, but Eclipse does not automatically detect the changes while the app is running. I have to constantly keep a tab of the bundle.js open, when a change to bundle.js is made, I have to go to that tab, which then causes eclipse to detect the file change. If you know a solution for that too, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @duffymo An Apple and an IntelliJ fanboy walks into a bar. How do you know? After a minute, everyone knows.

Comment: @duffymo, do you think this would actually solve my problem? (And is the ONLY way to solve the problem) It would cost massive overhead for weeks to switch to Mac and IntelliJ, so it'd be a last resort

Comment: I did not recommend that you buy a Mac.  I did recommend that you use IntelliJ to develop your Spring Boot project.  "Massive overhead" - really?  Download, install, start working.  If your Spring Boot project depends on Eclipse, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's unrelated, but I guess `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'target')` has to be `path.resolve(__dirname, 'target')` since the Maven `target` folder is in the project directory, not nested in `src`. The problem may or may not be caused by an infinite build loop: saving a changed file triggers the project builders, which in turn can cause via file changes to trigger webpack, which can cause file changes, which again triggers the project builders, and so on. Does the problem persist when you turn off _Project > Build Automatically_? Are you on Windows or on Linux?

Comment: @howlger, thanks for catching the extra 'src' before target. I fixed it but that didn't affect the project. I used to always have the "bundle.js" in an open tab in Eclipse, so that it would pick up the changes and serve them on the front-end. Closing that tab has made the issue a bit better, but didn't resolve it. (and now I have to go to the built folder and hit F5 every time I want to see a change). If I turn off 'build automatically', how do I trigger a build? I'm on win11

Comment: There's a separate preference on the **Workspace** preference page for it to refresh automatically, which solves one of those problems. Then you could manually kick off a build from the Project menu.

Comment: To track down the root cause, please first try both things nitind says: turn off _Build Automatically_ (which by the way is a feature many miss in other IDEs) and kick off builds manually and please also try to turn off automatically refreshing. If both have no effects, in _Window > Preferences: Language Servers_ try to turn off the _JavaScript-TypeScript Language Server_.

Comment: @howlger, nitind, thanks for the advice! The issues are much better with turning off automatic refresh + JavaScript-TypeScript Language Server. However, as howgler mentioned, now I do miss those features - developing JS in Eclipse isn't fun to begin with. W/o the js language server it's worse. The manual builds aren't too bad (performance problems are worse), but I'm still wondering about the root cause. When I open the bundle.js in Eclipse, it definitely does not like it at all. It seems to have a problem with that.